# How was the Cloak of Invisibility Created?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows, invisibility-cloak

I know the tale of the three brothers but does anyone know any convincing theories on how Ignotus Peverell created it?

Comment: [Magic.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt)

Comment: Also, could you please ask only *one* question? We don’t need one for each of the Hallows.

Comment: sorry, i wasnt going to ask this at first

Comment: @Adamant They probably have different answers, though.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Well, that’s why the question should have been “How were the Deathly Hallows created?”

Comment: @Adamant Is it worth me answering this question then? Or are they just going to be merged into one question?

Comment: I doubt they’ll be merged. I just think it would have been better to ask them together.

Comment: @TheDarkLord could you pls answer the question if you know it, it wont be merged.

Comment: I can't find the link anymore... It was on the old Pottermore or just some random theory, I don't remember... It mentioned Second brother used the veil and third brother used some Penseive buried under Hogwarts, something like that...

Comment: This is just some probably lame theory but you can go with itif you want to: https://youtu.be/TFnmdHERn_c

Answer (score 8):

### Probably using a Demiguise.

[Demiguises](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Demiguise), after all, have hair which is often used in the production of Invisibility Cloaks. From the entry in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*:

> The whole body is covered with long, fine, silky, silvery hair. Demiguise pelts are highly valued as the hair may be spun into Invisibility Cloaks.
>   <sub>*(Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, [Demiguise](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/demiguise-fantastic-beasts-introduction))*.</sub>

Many traditional Invisibility Cloaks were made from Demiguise hair, although you could also bewitch an ordinary cloak with spells of invisibility.

> “Ah, but the Third Hallow is a **true Cloak of Invisibility**, Miss Granger! I mean to say, it is not a traveling cloak imbued with a Disillusionment Charm, or carrying a Bedazzling Hex, or else woven from Demiguise hair, which will hide one initially but **fade with the years until it turns opaque**. We are talking about a cloak that really and truly renders the wearer completely invisible, and endures eternally, giving constant and impenetrable concealment, no matter what spells are cast at it."
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21, The Tale of the Three Brothers)*.</sub>

The trick with making an invisibility cloak is to make the invisibility complete, make the cloak resistant to the spells of others and make it durable so that it has longevity. Other cloaks had some of these features but were not the complete article.

> "It’s never occurred to me before, but I’ve heard stuff about charms wearing off cloaks when they get old, or them being ripped apart by spells so they’ve got holes in. Harry’s was owned by his dad, so it’s not exactly new, is it, but it’s just...perfect!”
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 21, The Tale of the Three Brothers)*.</sub>

It seems that Peverell perfected the art of bewitching his cloak in a way that no other witch or wizard managed to do. In other words, it was the **quality of his spells** that made Harry's Invisibility Cloak so uniquely powerful. The quality of Peverell's magic was sufficiently powerful that it didn't wear off over the years. It was superior either by the nature of the magic (i.e. he was using spells that others weren't aware of) or its strength. Basically, Peverell had superior magic. I don't think that we can be sure of the specific spells that he used.

Whatever spells he used, the quality of the Cloak would be increased if the original material he was modifying was intrinsically powerful. Demiguises have the power of invisibility so it stands to reason that cloaks made from their hair are more powerful than ordinary cloaks. The only downside to Demiguise Cloaks, according to Xenophilius Lovegood, is that they fade over time. If Peverell managed to overcome this flaw then he would've gone a long way towards creating the sort of Cloak described in the books. Considering the all-surpassing quality of the Peverell Cloak I think it's likely that he started with Demiguise hair, fashioned a Cloak from it and then performed a series of spells on it that allowed it to endure forever with no wear and tear.

Comment: *Or*, maybe Peverell had superior materials as well as superior magic. Other, inferior, Invisibility Cloaks only used Demiguise hair, but Peverell used something better. If you have a good argument to refute this possibility, I'll upvote :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not really. It could've been crazy good magic or a crazy good material. Or both. Either way, all we can really say with confidence is that he created a cloak that no-one else knew how to make. Perhaps it's slightly more likely that it was the spells which distinguished it since if there were magical materials which produced good cloaks the chances are someone else would've used them over the years. Demiguise hairs are the only canon ingredients mentioned. Not that that disproves something better.

Comment: Not sure about this answer. For me the chapter 21 quote included herein conflicts with the "probably using a Demiguise" supposition (which is bolded at the top). “Ah, but the Third Hallow is a true Cloak of Invisibility, Miss Granger! I mean to say, it is not...woven from Demiguise hair". I think your second last paragraph gets to the real crux of the matter.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister It's open to interpretation. Lovegood could mean that (according to him/legend) that the cloak isn't made using any of these methods. Or he could mean that it doesn't have the downsides of other cloaks made using those methods. As I say, Peverell could've used the same materials as others but just used superior spells to increase the power/longevity of his Cloak.

Answer (score -2):

This is total and utter fabrication by me, but perhaps, Peverell, after he had made the cloak itself, had had it charmed with [sacrificial protection](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sacrificial_protection).

For example, like how Harry is protected by his mother's sacrifice, the Cloak is also protected by a sacrifice from someone who died to give the Cloak its everlasting protection.

After all, if a horcrux is made by killing someone to hex the item, then it would follow that a hallow is made by someone willingly sacrificing themselves to charm the item.

Meanwhile, this does present a lot of questions, namely, who sacrificed themselves to create this cloak, and so I present this argument: Peverell himself.

The story goes that the third Peverell "evaded Death using the Cloak until he grew into an old man [and] finally gave the Cloak to his son and greeted Death as old friends" (http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Invisibility).

While he had made a very good cloak from the start as he had been "an immensely powerful wizard," (ibid.), it was when he passed it on to his son on his deathbed that he conferred on it "sacrificial protection," thereby making it the Cloak of the Hallows.

What do you think?

Comment: The sacrificial protection thing grants protection for a *person*, not a random item of clothing...

Comment: @TheDarkLord. Yes, I thought about that, too, but I have not found any mention of this protection being limited to just people. And it wasn't a random item of clothing; it was a special invisibility cloak that Peverell wanted to pass on to his progeny.

Comment: Have you found any evidence that *does* suggest that objects can be imbued with sacrificial protection? Because that's the crucial point.

Comment: @TheDarkLord ? This is like proving innocence. It is not known until it has been proven untrue. I'm more than happy to rescind my answer when proof comes forth that sacrificial protection applies only to people, but as it is right now, there is no proof either way, so the theory can still remain on the table.

Comment: @TheDarkLord. I see now. You're personally invested because you have also proposed an answer. But you do realize you contradict your own answer within your own answer? In fact, I had thought about incorporating your answer into mine at first, but then I had realized the contradiction.

Comment: Feel free to suggest improvements to my answer. Regardless of which answer is better your one would be improved by a quote from canon to support your points.

Comment: @TheDarkLord. Yes, I agree. But as I preface in my answer, I see this theory as a theory. And like the theory of dark matter, it might take [thirty years to prove](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2016/dec/31/dark-matter-existence-space-astronomers-us-experiment) or might never be able to be proved, but I think I provide enough canon-support for the observations that lead to my proof. Meanwhile, you see your answer as fact, and that, Dark Lord, is what will prove to be your undoing. (JK, Just wanted to throw the Dark Lord reference in.)

Comment: @TheDarkLord. Actually, if anything, reading your answer again, I think it lends support to a "hallowing" spell. How it's accomplished is again, theoretical, but I could see a possibility for the existence of one.